# find text box by web driver python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new in python, web driver in particular and I'm trying to find a text-box - the source code looks like this :

[image: please see the code in the link as follow]

I've tried this :

```
box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3F6QL._2WovP')
```

though no success. 
I'll be happy to add more information if needed - as I said I'm new here. appreciate the help

Comment: if you low grade please explain so I could learn for next time

Comment: what is the error that you are getting. also go through the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) this will help you understand best practices of SO. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have, I think, is that the class is compound - comprises of two classes: _3F6QL and _2WovP.
Selenium doesn't allow for finding elements by a compound class name.

Try this:

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_3F6QL') and contains(@class, '_2WovP')]")
```

or:

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_3F6QL') and contains(@tabindex, '-1')]")
```

(Not sure about the latter, though).

Also this should work:

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_1Plpp')]/div")
```